# How to catch "write failed: No space left on device (28)" error

Tags: php, error-handling

i'm using php to manage a bunch of hard disks.
Since the framework i use is only available for php i'm kinda stuck on this language.
So my question is:
Given an open like:

```
$fp = fopen(somefile,somemode);
```

How can i catch an ENOSPC error in case a write fails?

One option i can think of myself would be like this:

```
$oldlvl = error_reporting(0);
if(fwrite($fp, $somedata)<=0){
    $error = error_get_last();
    if(strpos(strtolower($error['message']),"no space left on device")!==false){
        // handle no space error!!!!!
    }
}
error_reporting($oldlvl);
```

anyone has a better way by not parsing the error message itself?

Comment: Get the [free space](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) amount value, and subtract `strlen($somedata)` from it? If the result is < 0 it means you have not enough space left

Comment: yeah, i also thought of this one - but this approach can deliver wrong results in case a file gets deleted between the error and the free space check - another problem arises if my function doesnt get a string to write to disk, but a stream - so i need to use stream_copy_to_stream e.g. sabredav suggest's using it